# No vertical scroll in browser

Tags: java, vaadin, vertical-scrolling

I'm developing a Vaadin application and am having extreme difficulty getting some aspects of the layout as I want. The major problem right now is that I can't seem to get a vertical scroll in my layout no matter how big the size of the content is or how small the browser window is..

I have read up on the subject, I know that the hLayout and the vLayout doesn't support scrollbars but the Panel do. I've tried in many different combinations to make it work but I've only managed to get a horizontal scrollbar to generate but never a vertical one.

Another problem is that I'm building the application inside an existing "template" provided by the company. This template contains a footer containing some copyright information. This footer doesn't seem to occupy any space in the browser window with regards to the content I'm adding, which causes when viewing on smaller screens the horizontal scrollbar to appear "underneath" the footer, non-accessible... I'll provide some of the code of how it looks now.

```
public class InventorySimCardTable extends M2MViewBase { //M2MViewBase extends VerticalLayout

    private final SPanel mainContent = Cf.panel("");
    private final SPanel tabPanel = Cf.panel("");
    private final SVerticalLayout tabcontent = Cf.vLayout();
    protected InventoryFilterPanel inventoryFilterPanel;

    @Override
    protected void initComponent() {
        setSizeFull();
        tabPanel.setSizeFull();
        tabPanel.getContent().setSizeUndefined();

        Table simCardTable = new Table();
        simCardTable.setWidth("1898px");
        simCardTable.setPageLength(15);

        tableContainer.setSizeUndefined();
        tableContainer.addComponent(simCardTable);

        mainContent.setWidth("99%");
        mainContent.setHeight("100%");
        mainContent.setContent(tableContainer);
        mainContent.setScrollable(true);

        centeringlayout.setSizeFull();
        centeringlayout.addComponent(mainContent);
        centeringlayout.setComponentAlignment(mainContent, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);

        tabPanel.addComponent(centeringlayout);

        addComponent(tabPanel);

    }
}
```

I would love to know if anyone sees any obvious errors in my code. And if anyone knows what property I can set on the footer CSS to have it occupy space in the content view so that the horizontal scroll doesn't appear underneath it. Thank you!

Comment: Refer to my post to read a full solution to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028870/how-can-i-make-a-verticallayout-scrollable-using-vaadin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I did to solve this issue was to structure the code as follows. This will create a vertical and horizontal scroll bar for the Panel holding my filter component and the table. Hopefully this can help someone with a similar problem.

```
@Override
    protected void initComponent() {

        super.initComponent();

        if(!tableCreated) {
            createSimCardsTable();
            tableCreated = true;
        }

        mainWindow = this.getWindow();
        Panel basePanel = new Panel("");

        basePanel.addComponent(inventoryFilterPanel);
        AbstractComponent separatorLine = Cf.horizontalLine(); //Of no signficance
        separatorLine.addStyleName("m2m-horizontal-line-list-separator");
        separatorLine.setWidth("99%");
        basePanel.addComponent(separatorLine);
        basePanel.addComponent(simCardTable);
        basePanel.setSizeFull();
        basePanel.getContent().setSizeUndefined(); // <-- This is the important part

        addComponent(basePanel);
        setExpandRatio(basePanel, 1);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

All Vaadin components have size undefined by default, so usually there is no need to call method `setSizeUndefined()`. Also there is no need to call `setScrollable(true)`, because it enables only programmatic scrolling possibility.

When I was trying to make a sense of scrolling appearance I wrote a simple skeleton of layout. Try this out as a content of the main window:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalSplitPanel;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Panel;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

public class Skeleton extends VerticalLayout {

public Skeleton() {
    setSizeFull();

    addComponent(new Label("Header component"));

    HorizontalSplitPanel splitPanel = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
    Panel leftComponent = new Panel();
    Panel rightComponent = new Panel();
    splitPanel.setFirstComponent(leftComponent);
    splitPanel.setSecondComponent(rightComponent);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 200 ; i ++) {
        leftComponent.addComponent(new Label("left"));
        rightComponent.addComponent(new Label("right"));
    }

    leftComponent.setSizeFull();
    rightComponent.setSizeFull();

    addComponent(splitPanel);
    setExpandRatio(splitPanel, 1);

    addComponent(new Label("Footer component"));
}
}
```

You should see scrollbars inside the nested panels. But if `setSizeFull()` is removed from `Skeleton` layout, then it is not limited in size (by default) and grows downwards  - then only the scrollbar of the whole window appears.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `styles.css`

```
.v-verticallayout > div {
    overflow-y: auto ! important;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Only issue was that scroll bar appeared on top of a text. I had to add one more line: `padding-right: 20px;`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to make your panel scrollable by calling setScrollable(true) method, but this will not work if you set some custom layout with setSizeFull() as this panel new layout.

If you exactly know that you application will be opened in device with small screen resolution, you simple can set for your "primary"/"main" layout some fixed width and height, or add some CSS style with params like min-width: {some value} px, min-height: {some value} px.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this post, I added `vertical.setSizeUndefined();` and started seeing vertical scrollbars.

```
setMainWindow(new Window(title ));

vertical.setSizeFull();
vertical.setHeight("100%");

toolbar = createToolbar();
vertical.addComponent(toolbar);
vertical.setExpandRatio(toolbar, 0.03f);

Component tree = buildTree();
vertical.addComponent(tree);
vertical.setExpandRatio(tree, 0.97f);
vertical.setSizeUndefined();
getMainWindow().setContent(vertical);>
```

Comment: I'm glad the post could help! It can be a bit hard finding info when you come across problems with Vaadin...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could fix this now (v6.8.14) is to **specify the height in px values** in stead of %

Answer (score 0):

Use CustomLayout, always. It's faster, more efficient and by controlling html and css easily you can acieve a graphically consistent result